# Twig logical operator not working for views result counter field in Drupal 8

Tags: twig, drupal-8

I've a simple views where I intend to use the "Views result counter" field for altering the output HTML. The total number of rows returned by the view is 6, and I've added below condition in a "Global: Custom Text" field

```
{% if counter > 3 %}
   <div>Greater than 3</div>
   <div>{{ counter }}</div>
{% else %}
   <div>Less than 3</div>
   <div>{{ counter }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

The output is as below

```
Less than 3
1
Less than 3
2
Less than 3
3
Less than 3
4
Less than 3
5
Less than 3
6
```

It never goes inside the If condition

Comment: Should work as is. See [here](https://twigfiddle.com/8djpba)

Comment: Yes this should work as is, but doesn't work for "Views result counter" field in Drupal 8 views

Comment: Then you will need to provide more information. Did you try to dump the variable? `{{ dump(counter) }}`

Comment: Yes I am dumping the variable in the second div <div>{{ counter }}</div>. It prints 4,5 and 6, but still prints "Less than 3 before it"

Comment: This seems to be a core bug in Drupal 8 - https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2764651 and https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional/issues/2867595

Comment: That's not dumping the variable though. See [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/discovering-and-inspecting-variables-in-twig-templates). `counter` is an object rather than a string or integer, so when twig tries to cast it to an interger, it will become `0`

Comment: Ugh, thanks @NPK, I thought I was going crazy when this wasn't working for me either.